# Simplest way to send HTTP GET and POST requests in Android, for my app's purposes

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I'm working on a prototype app to showcase an idea of mine -- so it need not be fully secure or gold standard, just needs to get the job done

I am wondering what the simplest option is to retrieve & parse, as well as publish JSON files from/to my Github repository. I am unsure which would be the easiest to implement. Right now, I see a few choices, but I am sure there are others you guys know of:

1. Using a Service class, which utilizes the `Handler`, `AsyncTask`, and  `HttpURLConnection` classes (I've done a tutorial on Barry Burd's Android Application Development All-in-One For Dummies, 2nd Edition in which I made a weather app that utilized a service). I am still somewhat iffy with this.
2. A much easier, straightforward usage of `HttpUrlConnection` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11939695/5484609). I understand this fully.
3. A more complicated version in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download). I do not really get this implementation either.

Also, the process can't freeze up the UI.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html  ....This will help you

Comment: there as no best choice. There is only somebody's **opinion**. You can't ask opinion-based questions here.

Comment: @VladMatvienko There can be a simplest choice of the ones available with regards to the needs of my app

Comment: I don't get why this is put on hold & downvoted. It's similar to other questions I see on SO all the time -- and the helpful answer I received clearly illustrates that there are simple libraries for my purposes...

Comment: there is just no score of simpleness. I can think that this one is simplest, and you can think that another one is more simple. But who of us is right? That's what is called **opinion-based**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939362/android-get-and-post-request/11939695#11939695
"Can anyone point me to a good implementation of a way to send GET and POST Requests. They are alot of ways to do these, and i am looking for the best implementation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some cleaner and better approaches. You can use lots of libraries for this purpose.

[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

[Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

These two are some of best libraries for calling webservise apis and I recommend `Retrofit` because it keeps your codes more clean and reusable.